# Why do Illustrator files end up larger than InDesign files?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, file-size

I just got some labels from a contractor, and they were designed in Illustrator. I started working exclusively in InDesign last year because I noticed the files sizes seem to be smaller and large projects end up being easier to work with.

I'm sure if I were to rebuild these labels in InDesign, using the same links from the Illustrator files, they would be *much* smaller, but I'm not sure why. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually Illustrator users will check the option to enable editing of a .pdf in Illustrator — this essentially includes a second version of the publication (AI) in the .pdf.

If you open a file in Adobe Illustrator and save out to a PDF-X/4 or some other standard press-ready file, disabling that option, the result is a much smaller file.

Comment: Ah, I think I'd noticed that on one AI file I worked with long ago. Thanks